# What's the easiest way to put the javascript animation to the background?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a JS animation, and I would like to put this animation behind the text and all the other elements.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://hub.chemdoodle.com/cwc/latest/ChemDoodleWeb.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hub.chemdoodle.com/cwc/latest/ChemDoodleWeb.js"></script>
    <title>Molecules</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="font-size:300%; text-align: center; font-family: Menlo;">Molecules</h1>
<script>
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    console.log('WIDTH', w, 'AND HEIGHT', h);
    var rotate3D = new ChemDoodle.RotatorCanvas('rotate3D', w, h, true);
    rotate3D.specs.atoms_useJMOLColors = true;
    rotate3D.specs.atoms_circles_2D = true;
    rotate3D.specs.bonds_symmetrical_2D = true;
    var exampleMolFile = 'Molecule Name\n  CHEMDOOD12250908183D 0   0.00000     0.00000     0\n[Insert Comment Here]\n 40 44  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1 V2000\n   -2.4201   -1.3169    0.4885   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -2.4007   -0.2197    0.6870   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -3.1630   -1.7585    0.5832   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -1.4920   -1.8472    0.1276   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -3.3129    0.2911    0.9878   O 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -1.4550    0.3261    0.5477   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.5339   -1.2844   -0.0016   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -1.5355   -2.6937   -0.0688   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -3.1138    1.0345    1.1162   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.5385   -0.2088    0.2615   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -1.3162    1.4114    0.6041   O 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.4574   -1.7528   -0.5024   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.3884    0.5420    0.1963   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.2569    1.5925    0.1057   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.6675   -2.4994   -0.0963   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    1.4380   -0.9689   -0.5556   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.2503   -1.9697   -1.3283   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    1.0495    0.4819    1.2355   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    1.0919    0.2175   -0.7577   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.1184    2.2301    0.5784   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.3921    2.0169   -1.0582   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    1.9358   -1.2202   -1.2354   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    2.1438   -0.9618    0.4030   N 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    1.6007   -0.6068    1.3817   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.5521    0.6440    1.9410   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    1.6648    1.1088    1.2152   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.5456    0.4220   -1.8161   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    1.8191    0.7140   -0.7698   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -1.4411    2.4257   -1.2400   O 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.1380    1.2410   -1.9394   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.1565    2.6937   -1.1652   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    2.6986   -1.9758    0.5733   C 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    2.1879   -0.5234    2.0289   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    1.0187   -1.2041    1.6545   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    0.7435   -0.0833   -2.4955   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -1.9229    1.9705   -0.8287   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n   -0.4917    1.3949   -2.7191   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    3.1158   -2.2288   -0.1548   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    3.3129   -1.8835    1.1918   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n    2.1618   -2.6206    0.8240   H 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0\n  1  2  2  0  0  0  0\n  1  3  1  0  0  0  0\n  1  4  1  0  0  0  0\n  2  5  1  0  0  0  0\n  2  6  1  0  0  0  0\n  7  4  2  0  0  0  0\n  4  8  1  0  0  0  0\n  5  9  1  0  0  0  0\n  6 10  2  0  0  0  0\n  6 11  1  0  0  0  0\n 10  7  1  0  0  0  0\n  7 12  1  0  0  0  0\n 10 13  1  0  0  0  0\n 14 11  1  0  0  0  0\n 12 15  1  0  0  0  0\n 16 12  1  0  0  0  0\n 12 17  1  0  0  0  0\n 13 18  1  0  0  0  0\n 13 14  1  0  0  0  0\n 13 19  1  0  0  0  0\n 14 20  1  0  0  0  0\n 21 14  1  0  0  0  0\n 16 22  1  0  0  0  0\n 19 16  1  0  0  0  0\n 16 23  1  0  0  0  0\n 18 24  1  0  0  0  0\n 18 25  1  0  0  0  0\n 18 26  1  0  0  0  0\n 19 27  1  0  0  0  0\n 19 28  1  0  0  0  0\n 21 29  1  0  0  0  0\n 30 21  1  0  0  0  0\n 21 31  1  0  0  0  0\n 23 32  1  0  0  0  0\n 23 24  1  0  0  0  0\n 24 33  1  0  0  0  0\n 24 34  1  0  0  0  0\n 27 35  1  0  0  0  0\n 27 30  2  0  0  0  0\n 29 36  1  0  0  0  0\n 30 37  1  0  0  0  0\n 32 38  1  0  0  0  0\n 32 39  1  0  0  0  0\n 32 40  1  0  0  0  0\nM  END';
    var mol = ChemDoodle.readMOL(exampleMolFile);
    rotate3D.loadMolecule(mol);
    rotate3D.startAnimation();
</script>
<p>
Hydrogen bonding plays a significant role in many chemical and biological pro- cesses, including ligand binding and enzyme catalysis. Consideration of hydro- gen-bonding properties in drug design is important because of their strong influ- ence on specificity of binding, transport, adsorption, distribution, metabolization, and excretion properties of small molecules. Their ubiquity and flexibility make hydrogen bonds the most important physical interaction in systems of biomole- cules in aqueous solution. Because hydrogen atoms comprise approximately one- half of the atoms within biological macromolecules and two-thirds of the atoms of the solvating water, hydrogen atoms, or protons, are found between almost every pair of non-covalently bonded heavy atoms in a biological system. Since the basic necessary condition for a hydrogen bond being present is that a proton lies be- tween the electron clouds of two other atoms and modifies their interaction in a manner that is not explicable in terms of the van der Waals (dispersion-repulsion) effect, hydrogen bonds almost rival van der Waals interactions in number.
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Now I have [image]

And

[image]

I don't own this text. I've put it just for the sake of the experiment.

I keep the frame for the sake of tracking. I can't find how to set x, y to 0,0 or somewhat like that, to make script appear not under the header `<h1>`, but behind it and on the same level.

How can I put this script to background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to position them over each other:

By wrapping the elements in divs, you can control the position and z-index for layering.

Markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        // YOUR CONTENT
    </div>
    <div id="animation">
        // YOUR CANVAS SCRIPT
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
#animation {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mattBBP/m0Lo5v6w/

You might want to make sure your content has a minimum height of your canvas animation to prevent it from cutting off:

```
#content {
    ...
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: Both the answers are good. Trick with the position absolute is wonderfully simple. I will choose your answer, as it's more detailed. Though both are good.

Answer (score 1):

add this CSS to H1 -> `position: aboslute; top: 0; left: 0;` - that is  the way. You can bind javascript result to some div and style it if you want another behaviour.